# sign in, sign out and sign up failed to redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my application controllers have the code before, which is supposed to redirect each type of user to, the appropriate page after sign in. When each type of user signed up, they should be redirect to root page, this is the same with log out. When, I click on log in or sign up button, I get redirect to the customer_dashboard instead of the log in or sign up page. When I hit log out, I get this error `Cannot redirect to nil!`, Before adding these redirect methods, when I click on each button, they would link to correct pages for log in and sign up. What is wrong with this code? Is there some logic that the code is missing in order to make this website work?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :authenticate!

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        case resource
            when Customer then customer_dashboard_path
            when Vendor  then stored_location_for(:vendors) || vendor_dashboard_path
        end
    end

    def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
        case resource
            when Customer then root_path
            when Vendor  then stored_location_for(:vendors) || root_path
        end
    end

    def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        case resource
            when Customer then root_path
            when Vendor  then stored_location_for(:vendors) || root_path
        end
    end

  def authenticate!
      if @current_user == current_customer
          :authenticate_customer!
          elsif @current_user == current_vendor
          :authenticate_vendor!
      end
  end

end
```

so i added skip_before_filter :authenticate! to all 4 controllers and the routing problem still persist.

```
class Vendors::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
# before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
# before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
skip_before_filter :authenticate!
  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `before_action :authenticate!` as it is being called before every action and routing you incorrectly.

I don't think what's your goal but you have to skip this before filter before some actions like your login or signup.

Comment: How should I fix this error? sorry I'm very new to rails development

Comment: just add `:skip_before_filter :authenticate!` in the controller where login and signup actions are defined.

Comment: Does it mean devise won't authenticate log in and sign up actions?

Comment: nope it means it will not call authenticate on simple login route action and will route you correctly.

Comment: so I will need to add that line to 4 controllers ? 2 sessions controllers for customers and vendors and 2 registrations controllers for customer and vendors?

Comment: Can you share `authenticate_customer!` & `authenticate_vendor!` method definitions ?